# Proof about prime filters

Tags: abstract-algebra, logic

I need some help in trying to prove this proposition :

“Let $F$ be a prime filter on a lattice $L$. If $ F = F_1 \cap F_2$ ( $F_1$ and $F_2$ filters) then $ F=F_1$ or $F=F_2$“

What I did :
Let $ x\vee y \in F$. Then $ x\vee y \in F_1$ and $ x\vee y \in F_2$.
Since F is prime, $x \in F_1 \cap F_2$ or $y \in F_1 \cap F_2$

Without losing generality, assume $x \in F_1 \cap F_2$. Then $x \in F_1$ and $ x \in F_2$ . Since $ y \in L$ and $F_1$ is filter, $ x\vee y \in F_1$. But $x\vee y \in F$. And since every filter is a sublattice… can I conclude that every element in $F_1$ is in $F$ and therefore $F = F_1$?
The last part is to be deduced for the “fact” (I dont know if true) that every element in a lattice/sublattice is the upper bound of some pair of elements (except for $0$).

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

*Hint*: Assume $F \neq F_1$ (pick an element $x \in F_1 \setminus F$. Thus every element of $L$ above $x$ is in $F_1$).
Now, you want to show that $F = F_2$.
Note that, since $F = F_1 \cap F_2$, we already have that $F \subseteq F_2$. Hence it is enough to show that, given an element $y \in F_2$, we have that $y \in F$.